# Daggers compilation PDF

Tags: pdf, compiling

[image]I have a problem with my latex code. I ve been using it for several years, but it is the first time that it happens. My problem is that when I compil the PDF, I have daggers almost everywhere mostly at the beginning of the section and at the end of the equation environment. And I have no idea how to get rid of them.

Do you know where could be the problem ?

Thanks

```
% debut d'un fichier latex standard
\documentclass[9pt,a4paper,twoside]{article} 

%%%Francisation
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%ecrire en fran?ais
\usepackage[francais,english]{babel}
%caracteres diacritiques
%\usepackage{lmodern}
%ecrire avec des accents sur mac
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%utilisation des guillemets
\usepackage[cyr]{aeguill}

%%%Packeages pour maths
%symbole math?matique
\usepackage{amsmath}   
\usepackage{amsthm}
%pr les ensembles math?matiques
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
%definis de nouveaux symboles comme l'ensemble vide
\usepackage{amssymb}
%police calligraphique
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
%package des unites
\usepackage[squaren,Gray]{SIunits}
%ecriture romaine 
\usepackage{modroman}
%numeration
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{listings} %code matlab
\usepackage{color} %red, green, blue, yellow, cyan, magenta, black, white
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0} % color values Red, Green, Blue
\definecolor{mylilas}{RGB}{170,55,241}
%package pour chimie
\usepackage{chemstyle}

%%%Packages images
%inclure des image   
\usepackage{graphics} 
%extension de graphics   
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pdftricks}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{listings}
```

Comment: Daggers? Can you show a minimal example of your code, maybe the output and a log file?

Comment: I can see the daggers on the screenshot.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This is a thing never seen before, so please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will eventually be possible to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Can you at least list the packages you include in the preamble and the document class?

Comment: @Bfrei: The problem is not to see the daggers, but to understand which code produces them.

Comment: I always use the same packages. So I haven't been changing my packages. So I think it doesn't come from the packages.

Comment: Which part of "Minimal Working Example" haven't you understood?

Comment: @Astrinus No need to get hostile, it’s Bfrei’s first day here ...

Comment: My code is very long. So what do u need else ?

Comment: @doncherry Yes, I know. But I feel like talking with a wall, when 3 different people asked for a MWE and the subsequent answers are useless to solve the problem.

Comment: @Bfrei The first part of solving a problem is narrowing down the source. Producing a MWE has proven to be the best strategy for that. If it’s not the packages, the problem should still show up without any packages, right? (But to be honest, I’m not sure that will happen.) In order for us to help you – without just wildly guessing and wasting everybody’s time – it’s pretty much necessary that you create a MWE, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Then we can try to reproduce the problem and look for its source. Have a look at tohcz’s link, it’s really helpful.

Comment: @Bfrei We neither want nor need *long* code. Make a copy of your file that you can mess around in. Then start commenting out parts (one strategy is to always cut 50%) and compiling and see if the problem persists. Try to leave as little code as possible. For more details, see in tohecz’s (second) link.

Comment: I would suspect problems with the document encoding of the file. Have you checked that?

Comment: Your preamble is classic case of [cargo cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult). Please throw it away and start with an empty one and add only those lines you _understand_ and that are _necessary_.

Comment: This should not have been closed. Please wait at least 24 hours after asking the OP for improvements to the question before voting to close. Also, if you downvote, please don't forget to revert the vote after the question is improved.

Comment: @MartinSchröder I think perhaps you meant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming

Answer (score 6):

Probably you are using the wrong input encoding. In `applemap.def`, the `\dag` is produced by input code 160 (hex: 0xA0):

```
\DeclareInputText{160}{\dag}
```

But 0xA0 is "non-break space" in ISO-8859-1/latin1 or ISO-8859-15/latin9.

- Check, that you use the correct input encoding option for package `inputenc`.
- If the dagger is indeed coming from "non-break space", check your editing/editor, how they got inserted.

Package `inputenx` might help to find a better input encoding option.
Also the editor might have options to set the encoding.